# Query JSON data column using Spark DataFrames

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with following structure:

```
root
 |-- pk: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sk: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tags: string (nullable = true)
```

Sample data that I am dealing with:

```
+--------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|pk      |sk       |tags                                                                                                 |
+--------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|123-8aab|464a-af2f|[{"type": "version","value": "2"},{"type": "version","value": "1"},{"type":"xyz","value": "version"}]|
|125-5afs|464a-af2f|[{"type": "version","value": "2"},{"type": "version","value": "1"}]                                  |
|562-8608|4c4d-464a|[{"type": "version","value": "2"},{"type":"xyz","value": "version"}]                                 |
|793-439b|4c4d-464a|[{"type": "version","value": "2"}]                                                                   |
+--------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The column tags is JSON and I am struggling to get the correct data for the column.
What I have so far:

```
tags_schema = spark.read.json(df_component.select('tags').rdd.map(lambda row: row[0])).schema
df_component = df_component.withColumn('tags', from_json(col('tags'), tags_schema))
df_component.printSchema()

root
 |-- pk: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sk: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tags: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

After running the above code, most of the values are returning null. Below is the sample data:

```
+--------+---------+------------+
|pk      |sk       |tags        |
+--------+---------+------------+
|123-8aab|464a-af2f|null        |
|125-5afs|464a-af2f|null        |
|562-8608|4c4d-464a|null        |
|793-439b|4c4d-464a|[version, 2]|
+--------+---------+------------+
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share the output after printing `tags_schema` and also the output of  `spark.read.json(df_component.select('tags').rdd.map(lambda row: row)).schema` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema identifies `tags` as a `struct` however the data inside tags is an `array` of `struct`,

Try using the following as the tag schema

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType,StructType, StructField, StringType

# from the example you have an array of structs with each struct having type and value
tags_schema = ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField("type",StringType(),True),
    StructField("value",StringType(),True),
],True),True)

df_component = df_component.withColumn("tagdata",from_json(col('tags'), tags_schema))
```

***Debugging conversion***

```py
# show original and new column
df_component.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ggordon. I also found this blog which was quite helpful as well. It does the same thing. Explicitly asks to define the schema. 
https://kontext.tech/column/spark/284/pyspark-convert-json-string-column-to-array-of-object-structtype-in-data-frame